# Forecasting a time series without trend and seasonality?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

Can I use ARIMA methods to forecast a time series without any trend or seasonality? 
If no, are there any other methods that I can use to do such forecasting?

Comment: 4 sure ....yes u can

Answer (score 3):

Personally I think this is exactly what you want in ARIMA, because no seasonality (which means no SARIMA) is simpler to do and non-stationarity (what happens when you have a trend) requires differencing which you would prefer not to do if possible.

Whether its realistic for real world social science data to have no trend and no seasonality for long is doubtful.